# Error on Tomcat with Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jersey

I have a problem trying to use Jersey on my Tomcat server. When I run my server and then try to go on the url "http://localhost:8080/RssApp/rest/test" I have the following error (RssApp is the name of my project):

> com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CreateAccount</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.team.RssServlet.CreateAccount</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CreateAccount</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and here my servlet:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("test")
public class CreateAccount{
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getIt() {
    return "Got it!";
}
}
```

I read on internet that it could come from

> com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages

like a wrong name or something, so just to see what type of error I would have I deleted "es" at the end to have just:

> com.sun.jersey.config.property.packag

I was expecting an error but I didnt had one, and then when I try with the url "http://localhost:8080/RssApp/rest/test" my browser displayed me "Got it!" lol.

I'm kind of lost, and I'm new to the JEE and web in general.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the package of CreateAccount??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting com.team.RssServlet.CreateAccount as a name of a Class instead of the package where you have rest class services.

Also that value should be a package name and you are including capital letters (bad practice)

Comment: Nice to help you !